# Get all parent records where their first child has a specific property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to create an ActiveRecord query to retrieve all parent records where their first child has a specific property.

```
Parent has_many children
Child has_one parent
```

Essentially I'm trying to do:

```
Parent.includes(:children).where('child.first.property = ?', 'something')
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Does it specifically have to be the first child?  And if so, what kind of ordering are you putting on the children (ie, first ordered by id, date, etc)?

Comment: Yes it must be the first child. I think if I don't set a default scope, the order will be 'created_at asc' right?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to perform those checks in your code and worry about optimization later.

```
Parent.select { |p| p.children.order("created_at asc").first.property == "something" }
```

That will end up loading up the first child for each parent though.  Another option would be to first join with children that have that attribute to narrow down the parents and then to perform the same check above.

```
Parent.joins(:children).where(:property => "something").group("parents.id").select { |p| p.children.order("created_at asc").first.property == "something" }
```